# Qt Qml: Dynamic number of moving axis aligned bounding boxes

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am writing a video display software capable of displaying multiple video streams. For this I have a GridView holding VideoOutputs in QML connected to a QAbstractListModel derived class in c++ which provides instances of an object with a QAbstractVideoSurface Q_PROPERTY. It's working quite beautifully so far.

The video frames I am displaying come with metadata, however, containing data for axis aligned bounding boxes. I don't know beforehand how many boxes there are, the number could even change on a frame by frame basis, their position and size is also not set.

Ultimately, it should look something like this:
[image: some AABBs in a video frame]

As I need to be able to display a few video streams at once, and preferably at 30+ fps, I need a fast method of drawing these boxes. Using QPainter on the QImage on which the QVideoFrame is based is rather slow so I was considering a few other approaches:

Using the QML object Rectangle in a Repeater with a c++ provided model (Was hoping to simply provide a QVariantList::fromVector() ): Could work, however I would need a lot of models which in turn I need to provide to QML with a model, and I would likely need to call begin/endResetModel every frame that the boxes change to cause QML to update - this is also very slow.

Using a Shader to draw the boxes: This is a rather difficult approach. I'm no stranger to shaders, but in Qt/Qml I don't know how to provide the shader with the information necessary.

Using OpenGL directly to draw the boxes: Again, I have no clue how to do this, but I think I could work it out if I googled.

**My question**: Which one, if any, of these approaches is the best? If none of these, which other approach could I use?

Thank you so much for taking the time to read my rather long question!

Comment: How about *one* element that draws all the boxes in one go, fed from data from the entire model?

Comment: The problem is that the frames for the different video streams don't have to arrive synchronously, they can be received with any offset and any frequency, so I'd have to have this central drawer working constantly. I'm currently trying to use the QPainter approach and see how much I can optimize this.

Comment: I'd say to try that, profile and go to raw OpenGL only if you see a huge overhead.